# how to change select value use python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, select

I want to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Python

but I used **select_by_value** can't get vaule

I have the following HTML code

```
<select id="play_date" name="play_date" onclick="javascript:GoodsInfo.GetPlayDate(this);" onmouseover="javascript:GoodsInfo.GetPlayDate(this);" onchange="javascript:GoodsInfo.GetPlayTime(this.value);">
                                        
<option value="" selected="">Select Date</option>
<option value="20230202" style="color: black;">Thu, Feb 02, 2023</option></select>
```

I am trying to get a list of the option values ('20230202') using Selenium.

At the moment I have the following Python code

```
 select_date = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='play_date']"))))
 select_date.select_by_value('20230202')
```

but it's always have is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with index 1
```

Any help or pointers is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: can you share the url of the page?

Comment: https://www.globalinterpark.com/detail/edetail?prdNo=23001060&dispNo=01003

Comment: I want to choose selected day in above page  <option value="20230225> but i can't select it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get error `NoSuchElementException` it means that you are using a wrong xpath/css_selector or that the element is inside an `iframe`. You can check by looking at the HTML

[image]

So your case is the latter, and to make the xpath work you have first to switch to the iframe, using `driver.switch_to.frame()` or better `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "product_detail_area")))

dropdown_date = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "play_date")))
options = []
# open menu so that options are loaded
dropdown_date.click()
# wait until options are loaded
while not options:
    options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#play_date option:not([value=''])")
    time.sleep(1)

# close menu
dropdown_date.click()
print('available options:')
for opt in options:
    print(opt.get_attribute('value'))

select_date = Select(dropdown_date)
select_date.select_by_value(input('enter value: '))
```

Comment: but i meet another issue after i click the buy the tickets and into the next web.